# Random number in label in python 3 and tkinter

Tags: python, random, tkinter

How can I make that in label generate some numbers for example:

some text(e.g.Input): #here generate numbers#

Input and Output are text in label
I want to make that number are generated every second in the label

Comment: Could you be more specific? A label widget has a text parameter, what do _input_ and _output_ mean?

Comment: I edited it, is is understandably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wait one second between each random number, use the `after` method and change the text in the scheduled function:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
import random

root = Tk()
label = Label(root)
label.pack()

def replace_text():
    label.config(text=str(random.random()))
    root.after(1000, replace_text)

replace_text()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?
Every time you press the button, a new random number is displayed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        self.text.set(random.randint(1, 10))
        self.ranNumLabel = tk.Label(self.frame, textvariable = self.text)
        self.genButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Generate Random Number', command = self.genRanNum)
        self.ranNumLabel.grid(row = 0)
        self.genButton.grid(row = 1)
        self.frame.grid()

    def genRanNum(self):
        self.text.set(random.randint(1, 10))
        # when text is updated, the Label associated with it also updated

def main():
    root = tk.Tk(className = ' Random Number Generator')
    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather confusing, but here is what I can answer...
To generate a random number use the `random.random()` function and the `label()` function in tkinter.

Here is an example:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
x=random.random()

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text=x)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Something like that, but that number are generated every second

Comment: Could've mentioned that earlier